# Windows Phone 8 - Twitter API

Tags: c#, twitter, windows-phone-8

I am doing some research and can't seem to find a definitive way to query Twitter's API to get a user's tweets on WP8 using C#.

The twitter user isn't my own account and all I want to do is retrieve tweets and **not** post any tweets.

Do I therefore need to Authenticate myself/my app? Is the `TweetSharp` library appropriate for my objective?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used the following example http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/wpapps/Twitter-Sample-using-f36bab75:

```
if (NetworkInterface.GetIsNetworkAvailable())
{
    //Obtain keys by registering your app on https://dev.twitter.com/apps
    var service = new TwitterService("abc", "abc");
    service.AuthenticateWith("abc", "abc");

    //ScreenName is the profile name of the twitter user.
    service.ListTweetsOnUserTimeline(new ListTweetsOnUserTimelineOptions() { ScreenName = "the_appfactory" }, (ts, rep) =>
    {
        if (rep.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            //bind
            this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => { tweetList.ItemsSource = ts; });
        }
    });
}
else
{

    MessageBox.Show("Please check your internet connestion.");
}
```

I created a new application user the twitter dev website: https://dev.twitter.com/user/login?destination=home. Once this was set-up, I essentially copied and pasted the keys within the `AuthenticateWith` and `TwitterService` methods.

I haven't solved exactly how I shall display the data but, at runtime, I can see data being passed in.