# Twitter Integration In windows Phone 7

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I want to get the user information from the twitter and show in windows phone 7. I found some examples for twitter integration.

[Link 1](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Twitter-Sample-using-0dfcce61/view/Discussions)

[Link 2](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Latest-Twitter-integration-a42e8bb6/view/Discussions)

But in this examples i can only login to the twitter. I can not post or can not get the user information. Can any one provide a sample application or links for windows phone 7 twitter integration.

After getting login i try like this:

```
 private void btntest_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        string newURL = string.Format("https://api.twitter.com/1.1/users/show.json?screen_name={0}", userScreenName);

        WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
        webClient.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(webBrowser_Navigated);
        webClient.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri(newURL));
    }

    void webBrowser_Navigated(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
    {


        if (e.Error != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error ");
            return;
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Result==> " + e.Result);
        //List<Tweet> tweets = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Tweet>>(e.Result);
        //this.lbTweets.ItemsSource = tweets;
    }
```

But here i can not get the user information. Please help me to get the user infoemation.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally i found the Solution..!!! :-)

```
public void GetTwitterDetail(string _userScreenName)
    {
        var credentials = new OAuthCredentials
          {
              Type = OAuthType.ProtectedResource,
              SignatureMethod = OAuthSignatureMethod.HmacSha1,
              ParameterHandling = OAuthParameterHandling.HttpAuthorizationHeader,
              ConsumerKey = AppSettings.consumerKey,
              ConsumerSecret = AppSettings.consumerKeySecret,
              Token = this.accessToken,
              TokenSecret = this.accessTokenSecret,
          };

        var restClient = new RestClient
        {
            Authority = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1",
            HasElevatedPermissions = true
        };

        var restRequest = new RestRequest
        {
            Credentials = credentials,
            Path = string.Format("/users/show.json?screen_name={0}&include_entities=true", _userScreenName),
            Method = WebMethod.Get
        };

        restClient.BeginRequest(restRequest, new RestCallback(test));

    }

    private void test(RestRequest request, RestResponse response, object obj)
    {
        Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Content==> " + response.Content.ToString());
            Console.WriteLine("StatusCode==> " + response.StatusCode);
        });
    }
```

Now i got the User's In formations..!!! 5 days struggling comes to end..!! Thanks to all..!!

Answer (score 1):

Did you try using the `Tweetinvi` API from `Codeplex`, where you could grab the user details as well you could post tweets.

[Tweetinvi a friendly Twitter C# API](https://tweetinvi.codeplex.com/documentation)

Have a look at this one too:

[Windows Phone 8 - Twitter API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20610485/)

Comment: Hi @Kulasangar.. I am looking for windows phone 7. But it seems WP8. Is this work in WP7 also???

Comment: @Vijay nop it's for WP8. Have a look at these for WP7 then, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22189230/windows-phone-7-how-to-post-tweet-to-twitter
http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/raj1979/how-to-make-a-twitter-application-using-windows-phone-7/

Comment: Yes.. Already i seen this link also. But no use for my problem. I am also getting the same error. But can not resolve from the answer which is provided in that link.